# Regular Expression should not match other prefixes

Tags: regex

if for instance I have these words

- john=14
- adam=21
- ben=11
- john=18
- johan=17
- john=141
- ...

and the task is to find all occurences of `john=14`.
I came up with the following regular expression: `.*=[^14].*\n` which matches every string without a leading 1 after the equal sign.
However, I want to exactly match only `john=14` in this example (and also for permutations of this example). It doesn't matter if there are one or more `john=14`. I thought about negation of the regular expression, such that I want to find every string that isn't equal to the one I want to find but I had a problem with the regular expression (`[^\bjohn\b=14]\n`).

Any help would be appreciated :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead.

```
^(?!john=14$).*
```

Negative lookahead at the start asserts that the string going to be matched won't contain the exact `john=14` string. If yes then match all the chars.

**or**

```
^(?!.*=14$).*
```

Comment: or `^(?!.*\bjohn=14$).*`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question: Now given a list full of `john=random number`, I want to extract all `john=14` from this list, by matching all `john=random number` and "deleting" those but keep any other gibberish in the input intact.
For example (three lines): john=12 adam=15 john=14. The result should be adam=15 and john=14.

Comment: ask this as a new question with detailed explanation.